# Android BACK key click twice

Tags: android, android-button

I would like to show something when BACK key was clicked once, and close app when clicked twice.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (/* BACK_KEY_was_clicked_once_again */) {
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            text.setText(log);
        }

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Sorry I didn't explain it well

Main (lets say) view of my app is: text.setText(log), but when I click "info" button in menu then: text.setText(info). When "info" is set I want BACK button to: text.setText(log), when "log" is set I want Back button to close my app.

Now I realized what I really want to do, and changed code to this:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
  if (text.getText() == log) {
    finish();
  }
  else
  {
    text.setText(log);
  }
  return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use an Class level field   as flag  to check if Back Button if pressed twice or not as :

```
 public static boolean backtwice=false;  //this is flag

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (backtwice) {
           backtwice=false;  //reset here
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            text.setText(log);
           backtwice=true;  //set true if first time back pressed
        }

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: one minute slower than yours and you made better explanation. (-:

Comment: Ok , what if I(or a kid) pressed it once(it sets to true) accidentally and after some gap of say 30sec~ > , I(or a kid again) presses back button. OMG it quits app in middle, but the question(or subject) here should be "QUIT AN APPLICATION ON CLICKING THE BACK BUTTON TWICE SUCCESSIVELY."In less than a maximum of 2~3 seconds, ELSE reset the FLAG = default values.

Answer (score 3):

not sure about what you are trying to do, but

```
private boolean backPressed = false;
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (backPressed == true) {
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            backPressed = true;
            text.setText(log);
        }

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

might solve your problem...?

Comment: Not exactly, I've tried similar solution with int 0,1 but it is not what I need. It should work like this: when I click button "info" in my menu there is an info about program set on "text".When I click back-button I want to set "log" on "text". Maybe I shold write function which check double click in certain time?

Answer (score 1):

Just add in activity:

```
private boolean doubleBackPressedOnce = false;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // .... other stuff in my onResume ....
    this.doubleBackPressedOnce = false;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }
    this.doubleBackPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.exit_press_back_twice_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a static boolean flag

initialize flag as false by default.

Now change code like this

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
      if(flag == false)//indicates back button is pressed 1st time {                
           flag=true;
           //do operation for first back button press
           text.setText(log);              
       }
    else //indicating pressed 2nd time
   {
        finish();
    }
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean twiBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // .... other stuff in my onResume ....
    this.twiBackToExitPressedOnce= false;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (twiBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }
    this.twiBackToExitPressedOnce= true;
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.exit_press_back_twice_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Show something when BACK key was clicked once, and close app when clicked twice

This can be easily handled using the [`DoubleBackPress Android Library`](https://github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/DoubleBackPress), created exactly for situations like this. It provides easy to use APIs without any of the handling hassle.

Just do the following :

```
FirstBackPressAction firstBackPressAction = new FirstBackPressAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionCall() {
        // TODO : whatever needs to be shown on the First Back key press 
    }
};

DoubleBackPressAction doubleBackPressAction = new DoubleBackPressAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionCall() {
        // TODO : Exit app code
    }
};

DoubleBackPress doubleBackPress = new DoubleBackPress()
        .withDoublePressDuration(3000)   // msec to wait for second back press
        .withFirstBackPressAction(firstBackPressAction)
        .withDoubleBackPressAction(doubleBackPressAction);
```

Finally, override your back press behaviour with the desired behaviour.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    doubleBackPress.onBackPressed();
}
```

[An example GIF of similar behaviour](https://github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/DoubleBackPress#ToastDisplayExample)